# Buttons show multi scrollView, leads other buttons out of layout

Tags: android, xml, button, scrollview

i create three Buttons in xml file activity, and when i click to some button the scroll will shown, that's leading to hide the others button in the bottom of screen, how can i solve it:

xml structure:

```
<LinearLayout>

<!-- Section 1 -->
    <Button/>

    <ScrollView>

        <TableLayout>
    <!-- Components -->
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

<!-- Section 2 -->
<Button/>

    <ScrollView>

        <TableLayout>
    <!-- Components -->
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

<!-- Section 3 -->
    <Button/>

    <ScrollView>

        <TableLayout>
    <!-- Components -->
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

my full code: activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Section 1" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/Section_1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:stretchColumns="1" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Section 2" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/Section_2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:stretchColumns="1" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 2"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 2"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 2"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 2"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 2"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 2"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 2"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 2"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 2"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 2"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 2"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 2"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 2"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 2"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 2"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 2"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 2"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 2"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 2"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 2"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 2"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Section 3" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/Section_3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:stretchColumns="1" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Section 3"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private List<ScrollView> listOfScrolls = new ArrayList<ScrollView>();
private List<Button> listOfButtons = new ArrayList<Button>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listOfScrolls.add((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.Section_1));
    listOfScrolls.add((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.Section_2));
    listOfScrolls.add((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.Section_3));

    listOfButtons.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.button1));
    listOfButtons.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.button2));
    listOfButtons.add((Button) findViewById(R.id.button3));

    int index = 0;
    for (Button btn : listOfButtons) {
        final int fi = index;
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (listOfScrolls.get(fi).getVisibility() == LinearLayout.VISIBLE) {
                    listOfScrolls.get(fi).setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
                } else {
                    listOfScrolls.get(fi).setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });

        ++index;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for every scroll view

```
<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/Section_1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="gone" >
```